# Dynamic default selected option

Tags: vue.js, selected

I have component to edit a product, in the `select` element i want to make the product category option as the default option, if that product category name is equal to the name in the category array being looped, then i want that option to be selected by default, but it's not working as expected.

```
const props = defineProps({
 product: Object, 
 categories: Object 
});

const form = useForm({
    category: "",
});



<select v-model="form.category">
 <option v-for="category in categories"
 :selected="category.name == product.category">
   {{ category.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default {
  props: {
    product: Object,
    categories: Array,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const form = ref({
      category: props.product.category || '', // Set the default value based on product.category
    });

    return { form };
  },
};
```

Comment: with that, there is no need to set a ```selected``` attribute.